# How do I write this Cloudsearch query

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I have cloudsearch records with the following fields (among others):

```
status: eg 'PROPPOSAL', 'ACCEPTED', 'CANCELLED' etc
created_at: eg 2018-06-29T11:03:44Z
```

I need a query that can satisfy the following:

> No proposals older than 31 days

How do I write that as a query? At the moment I seem only to be able to write queries that return ONLY records where the status is not PROPOSAL or queries that return only records that are younger than 31 days

Both of which are wrong.

The query should return records regardless of date UNLESS they are PROPOSAL, in which case apply the 31 days rule as well.

How can I do this? I tried something like:

```
(and 
    (and 
        (range field=created_at ['2019-07-21T14:31:30Z',}) 
        (not field=status 'PROPOSAL')
    )
)
```

Which does not do what I need